# how to copy cleanupSettings from eclipse to intellij?

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

I have a number of xml files, exported from eclipse, and I would like to stick to a common protocol with my eclipse-using colleagues. It has been suggested to me, that I can simply import the settings into IDEA. Now, I've figured out the files that I could need and how to import them (formatting, for example).

I am a bit confused about `cleanupSettings.xml`. What does it do? and will I gain any benefit in having the same "cleanup" as my colleagues. If so, how do I import them?

Or a better way to ask this, is : how do I, in intellij, do "cleanup" tasks, such as organise imports, and know that, when I reformat, these things will happen. Imagine I have a very specific action, such as prepend the source file with "asdf"

Comment: There are no standard names for exported configuration files so we can't be sure what this is from the name. My guess would be that this is the "Java > Code Style > Cleanup" profile which controls what the "Source > Clean up" action does.

Comment: Aren't those eclipse paths? I require intellij paths, in order to find where I might import the settings.

Comment: You asked what it does and I told you what it does in Eclipse. I don't use Intellij so I can't tell you anything about that.

Comment: roger that. Thanks.